# Place an image or a css style icon inside the cell (of the grid) that is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is my code to create table with php by looping. I add an onclick function in each . So that on clicking a particular cell the background color is changed.  Now i want to place a particular image..inside each cell that is being clicked..but am not able to figure out that function.

**I want to write a function such that an image is placed when clicked.**

```
/* 
 * javascript function that changes color of the cell.
 * 
*/

 <script>
    function changeColor(elem)
    {     
    elem.style.background = "red";     
    }
 </script>
```

**Table created in php**

```
<?php
    $rows = 10; // define number of rows
    $cols = 4;// define number of columns

    echo "<table border='1'>";

    for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){

        echo "<tr>";
            for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
                   echo "<td onclick=\"changeColor(this)\" > ".$tr." ".$td."</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
elem.innerHTML = '<img src="path/to/image.png" />';
```

Comment: [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) is a void element.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
  elem.style.background = "red";
```

with this for `javascript`

```
  elem.style.backgroundImage ="url('path/myimage.jpg')";
```

use this for `jQuery`

```
  $(elem).css('background-image', "url('path/myimage.jpg')");
```

> **FOR DRAWING A CIRCLE TRY THIS**  *(ADD THIS POINT TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION AS WELL)*

You might want to have a look at [HTML5 CANVAS](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

You will have to add a `canvas` tag in the `td` and send its reference to the function

```
    var offsets = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var top_C = offsets.top;
    var left_C = offsets.left;
    var bottom_C= offsets.bottom;
    var right_C= offsets.right;
    var y_C= ((bottom_C-top_C)/2); // Y- Co=ordinates
    var x_C=((right_C-left_C)/2);  // X- Co=ordinates
    var ctx=elem.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x_C,y_C,40,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
```

You might have to do try it a couple of times to get the perfect radius that fits your cell.
The third argument in `ctx.arc()`

Comment: instead of adding an image can i draw a circle dynamically with css ?

Comment: @jasmin Check the update made in the answer, also specify and make clear this requirement in the question as well.

Comment: ur code dynamically drawsa circle...but as we r specifying x& y co oedinates of d arc, it is drawn at that particular point..and not at the point where the mouse is clicked.

Comment: @jasmin I have edited the answer for finding the X and Y co-ordinates. Have a look at it..

Comment: can u plz look into the forum of ur website now..?                         Is there a way to identify the second click inside the same cell ? yes the code for drawing circle is working ty :)

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
elem.style.backgroundImage ="url('"+imageUrl +"')";
```

**Jquery**

```
$('elem').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```